# Booleans in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, boolean

I am using a optional variable `BUILD_X` flag to decide whether to build X based on user input.

```
BUILD_X=true
while getopts "B:" option; do
  case "$option" in
    B) BUILD_X=$OPTARG;;
  esac
done

if (( $BUILD_X == true )); then
    body
fi
```

I am observing that even if I give BUILD_X false from the terminal as an input to script, it still executes the body. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: The shell's only primitive data type is the string. `false` is simply the string `"false"` and does not have a boolean value.

Comment: @tripleee so how do I correct this code ?

Comment: The usual solution would be to not have an argument for the option and just set the variable if the option is present. So `getopts "B"` and if that is true then set `X_BUILD=""`; then in your conditional you can simply say `if [[ "$X_BUILD" ]]; then`

Comment: @tripleee using `if [[ "$BUILD_X" == true ]]` works but (( )) round brackets are not working ? I don't understand why because both can be used for comparisions

Comment: `(( ... ))` is mathematical context, it works fine for numbers but this is a string.